# Clausing a nested BigQuery doesn't as expected

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, nested

I am basically trying to query a column called hits.CustomDimension.index , so I had to nest multiple times in order to be able to access the data. I am trying to filter so it only shows up the rows where hits.CustomDimension.index = 16 with the query below, but its returning all of the CustomDimension rows for any observation which has CustomDimension.index = 16 somewhere.
Not sure what I am doing wrong? As you can see in the image I added, still all the custom dimensions where customDimension.index = 16 are appearing, i only want that one flattened.

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(hit, hits)

FROM ***,

UNNEST(hit) h

CROSS JOIN UNNEST(customDimensions) cd 

WHERE cd.index = 16 AND timeOnSite IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
SELECT * 
FROM ******.ga_sessions_export, 
UNNEST(hits) h 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(h.customDimensions) cd 
WHERE cd.index = 16 
LIMIT 10
```

The problem in your original query is that you filtered not by hits.customDimensions but rather by separate field which is named customDimensions

[image]

vs.

[image]

Comment: Same issue. It is returning all of the custom dimensions on any observation where the custom dimension 11 appears

Comment: Then I think you should better define your question with more details / examples

Comment: Read carefully again my answer! You might notice something useful. Which was the point of the answer

Comment: @linacar231 this solution is right. You are probably confusing the fields (GA data has three fields named customDimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Custom dimensions are stored as an array. If you only want to see your specific custom dimension, you can exclude hits and hit columns from the select statement.

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(hits, hit),
FROM ******.ga_sessions_export, 
UNNEST(hits) hit,
UNNEST(customDimensions) cd
WHERE cd.index = 16
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This is still returning any observation where cd.index = 16 appears! attached an image of how it looks

Comment: Ah, I see. You only want to see cd.index = 16. I'm editing it now.